# Android - Cascading drawable folders and default drawables

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I have the following drawable folders

```
/drawable/
/drawable-hdpi/
/drawable-ldpi/
/drawable-mdpi/
/drawable-xhdpi/
```

If I have an image resource, do I need to create 5 (or 4?) different resolution versions of the file? Let's say I make just two versions and put them in their respective folders:

```
/drawable/
/drawable-hdpi/image.png
/drawable-ldpi/
/drawable-mdpi/image.png
/drawable-xhdpi/
```

What happens when someone on a LDPI or XHDPI device visits an Activity that needs to display `image.png`? Does it just not show it?  Does the app crash? Or does Android follow a resource cascading system, show the version that is nearest to the current screen density?

Also, in this case I don't have an `image.png` in the `/drawable/` folder. Is this bad? Should every single resource have (at minimum) a version in the `/drawable/` folder?

Also, if you have specified all 4 screen density drawable folders (xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi), then what is the point of the normal `/drawable/` folder? When will it ever get used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I have an image resource, do I need to create 5 (or 4?) different
>   resolution versions of the file?

No, you don't have to

> What happens when someone on a LDPI or XHDPI device visits an Activity
>   that needs to display image.png? Does it just not show it? Does the
>   app crash? Or does Android follow a resource cascading system, show
>   the version that is nearest to the current screen density?

Android uses a nice cascading system for its resources. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) page explains it a bit. <strike>Afaik LDPI devices use the MDPI resource if a LDPI resource isn't available, XHDPI uses HDPI resources. (I could be a bit off, I can't recall the exact rules) Your app doesn't crash.</strike> 
Your app crashes if you only have higher resolution resources than the screen can take.

> Also, in this case I don't have an image.png in the /drawable/ folder.
>   Is this bad? Should every single resource have (at minimum) a version
>   in the /drawable/ folder?

No, not necessary.

> Also, if you have specified all 4 screen density drawable folders
>   (xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi), then what is the point of the normal
>   /drawable/ folder? When will it ever get used?

The drawable folder is for images that don't need scaling, and things like shape drawable resource XML files etc.

Comment: Thanks. With regards to your knowledge of LDPI using MDPI and XHDPI using HDPI, where did you get this info? Or is this just from testing?

Comment: See my edit, added the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: FYI, I found this on that page `However, if the only available resources are larger than the current screen, the system will not use them and your application will crash if no other resources match the device configuration (for example, if all layout resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier, but the device is a normal-size screen).`

Comment: cool, I didn't knew that actually, every day something new ;) Reflected it in the answer for clarity to others.

Comment: The above quoted text refers to screen SIZE not screen DENSITY. Their are no "resolution" specific resources.

Comment: Well, you can in fact have a /drawable-hdpi-1024x600/ folder for example (specifically for WSVGA devices like the Samsung Galaxy Tab, Amazon Kindle Fire) though I think with recent updates it is not the preferred way to solve such things :)